# KendoUI - Multiselect - Cascade - Issue with JSON Filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, laravel, kendo-ui

I am facing issue on receiving correct value after filtering on multiselect data.

```
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var productsDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                type: "json",
                serverFiltering: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "/api/incident/issue",
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (data) {
                        return kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap.call(this, data);
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#products").kendoMultiSelect({
                autoBind: false,
                dataTextField: "IssueName",
                dataValueField: "IssueID",
                dataSource: productsDataSource
            });

            $("#suppliers").kendoMultiSelect({
                autoBind: false,
                dataTextField: "CategoryName",
                dataValueField: "CategoryID",
                dataSource: {
                    type: "json",
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: "/api/incident/category"
                        }
                    }
                },
                change: function () {
                    var filters = buildFilters(this.dataItems());
                    productsDataSource.filter(filters);
                }
            });

            function buildFilters(dataItems) {
                var filters = [],
                    length = dataItems.length,
                    idx = 0, dataItem;

                for (; idx < length; idx++) {
                    dataItem = dataItems[idx];

                    filters.push({
                        field: "CategoryID",
                        operator: "eq",
                        value: parseInt(dataItem.CategoryID)
                    });
                }

                return {
                    logic: "or",
                    filters: filters
                };
            }
        });
    </script>
```

It looks i have an issue on this section

```
                  filters.push({
                        field: "CategoryID",
                        operator: "eq",
                        value: parseInt(dataItem.CategoryID)
                    });
```

At the `operator: "eg",`

As i can see the post occurs without an issue like this:

```
/api/incident/issue?%24inlinecount=allpages&%24format=json&%24filter=CategoryID%20eq%201
```

Receiving the data but without correct filtering, any help with the JSON operator (equivalent) please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved. Changed the value at `serverfiltering:` from `true,` to `false,`.